# Jquery function doesn't trigger on first click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery function that expands the comments of a thread :

```
function ExpandComments() {
$('.showcomments').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).closest('#commentsection').find('.threadComments');
    $('#threadComments').not(comment).slideDown();
    comment.stop().slideToggle();
});
}
```

HTML :

```
        <h6><a class="showcomments" href="javascript: ExpandComments()">  comments</a></h6>

        <script> $('.threadComments').hide();</script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="threadComments">

                <div class="large-2 columns small-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=[img]"/></div>
                <div class="large-10 columns"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet nulla ham qui sint exercitation eiusmod commodo, chuck duis velit. Aute in reprehenderit</p></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="threadComments">
                <div class="large-2 columns small-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=[img]"/></div>
                <div class="large-10 columns"> <textarea id="commentText" style="resize: none;"></textarea></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

It works ok , only it does not trigger on the first click

Comment: Are you wrapping your code with a document ready handler?

Comment: No , I guess I should mention that the page is loaded via load()

Comment: `$('#threadComments')` should be `$('.threadComments')`.

Comment: If you're using jQuery (or Vanilla Javascript) to attach event handlers, you don't need this in your markup: `href="javascript: ExpandComments()"`.

Comment: Selector for classes use `.` notation, and not `#`, which is used for IDs.

Comment: I've changed it to the correct syntax but apparently it still doesnt work on first click , Right now I'm trying the answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment: *I guess I should mention that the page is loaded via load()*

As you are loading HTML using `.load()` then you need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*Use*

```
<h6><a class="showcomments" href="#">comments</a></h6>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '.showcomments', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(this).closest('#commentsection').find('.threadComments');
    $('.threadComments').not(comment).slideDown(); //Also in this a typo use .threadComments
    comment.stop().slideToggle();
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performace and you certainly don't need `ExpandComments` function

Comment: Is it $('.threadComments').not(comment).slideDown(); or  $('#threadComments').not(comment).slideDown();?

Comment: @RGS, Great eye I completely missed that